# Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension with $Gal(L/K)=A_{4}$. Prove that there is no intermediate subfield $M$ of $L/K$ such that $[M:K]=2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension with $Gal(L/K)=A_{4}$. Prove that there is no intermediate subfield $M$ of $L/K$ such that $[M:K]=2$.

Please tell me a hint. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This might help http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/A4noindex2.pdf

Comment: Very nice hint! Thank you very much. I understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such an intermediate extension corresponds to a subgroup of what index in $A_4$? Would this conflict with any properties that $A_4$ has, something about lack of <s>solvability</s> subgroups of index $2$  maybe.

Comment: $A_4$ is solvable...

Comment: $A_4$ is solvable. Perhaps you want to infer something about the normal subgroups of $A_4$

Comment: Yes, sometimes I confuse $4$ and $5$. Years of programming have made me very susceptible to off by one errors.