# Abstract Algebra: prove it is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-groups, self-learning, cyclic-groups

I have question in referring to below link.

[Question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571546/let-l-k-be-a-galois-extension-with-gall-k-a-4-prove-that-there-is-no-in) Suppose if I have [M:K]=2 and I know that K is subset of M. M:=$\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(f(x))$ where f(x)=x$^4$+x+1. Then how this will be cyclic?

I know is f(x) is 16 elements. And vector space between M -> K is 2. Also we can know that vector space between $\mathbb{Z}_2$ -> K is 2. Therefore K has 4 element (which will be I suppose (x$^3$,x$^2$,x,1)). Now how can I know that it is cyclic.

Note: K is non-zero.

Total Two question I have

1. How to prove it is cyclic?
2. How to prove it is cyclic without galios theory?

Comment: You need to be **way** more careful when you write: (1) what do you mean with "I know f(s) is 16 elements"?? I think you *actually* meant that M has 16 elements, which is true. (2) What does "we can know that vector space between $\;\Bbb Z_2\to K\;$ is 2"?? Did you mean the dimension of M over K? (3) In your point (2) above I think you meant *Galois Theory* . (4) Finally, to prove **what** is cyclic?? ...

Comment: Yeah, I was about to write the same thing. @user1413 : please don't get discouraged by our comments about improving the English in your questions :) We're very aware of the difficulties nonnative speakers face. Just do your best and try to learn from the advice on improvement!

Comment: Thank you yes that what I meant. Sorry for not writing properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that $K$ has $4$ elements.

If you're talking about the additive group of $K$ being cyclic, then that is not correct. Since the field $F_2$ is of characteristic $2$, every element of $K$ satisfies $x+x=0$, so the additive group of $K$ is just the Klein $4$ group.

If you're talking about the multiplicative group $K^*$, then yes, $K=\{0,a,b,c\}$ for some nonzero elements $a,b,c$, and $0$ is just the zero of the additive group. Then $\{a,b,c\}$ is a group of order $3$, but there is only one group of order $3$, namely the cyclic group of order $3$.

Comment: I didn't got you second part which is multiplicative group

Comment: @user1413 The nonzero elements of any field form a group by using the field multiplication as the binary operation.

Comment: Oh yes got it thank you.

Comment: I am still looking how to prove with Galois Theory?

Comment: @user1413 In your question you said *without* Galois theory. Which do you mean?